Detect and Localize Abrupt Changes on a Noisy Non Periodic Signal
I have a set of some 5000 x,y datapoints. They plot a smooth curve with large gradient and curvature at the right. There is high-freq noise that varies in amplitude from dataset to dataset, but the amplitude is always constrained to a reasonably narrow band. No wild single-point outliers. Occasionally there is an abrupt change in the signal: a spike, a flat-top peak, a step-up, or a step-down. My goal is to tell if a given curve has any such anomaly or not. The algorithm must be fully automated, no runtime manual tuning of parameters is possible.
I have done a lot of reading, and I also developed a decent method based on piecewise linear fits. My method does not perform well on subtle anomalies. And it was also a lot of work to develop it and to tune it. I suspect that is an easy problem for an expert, I would like to hear from people with hands-on experience with 1D noisy non-periodic data. What approach would you choose? I am prototyping in Python, deploying in C++98. Sorry, I cannot post my data, it is proprietary.


Can you post a picture of your data? Or a few snippets that covers the anomalies you’re (not) interested in?

OK, I added a picture with synthetic data that is pretty close to what I am working on.

@RadimCernej gradient analysis seems appropriate here as at the discontinuity there would be there would be a significantly higher gradient value than all other locations. You might also potentially try wavelets, but not sure how good of results for an automated algorithm you’d get

@Baddioes I tried using the 1st and also the 2nd derivative. The derivatives were too noisy to be useful. I tried also Savitzky-Golay smoothing discrete differentiating operators, I got mediocre results. I am thinking to try a wide Gaussian differentiating kernel.

Have you tried HMM / Viterbi stuff? It's generally good for finding maximum-likelihood changes between discrete modes of operation. You do have to give it some cost for the current distribution slowly changing, vs a sudden jump to a new setup

@cloudfeet There are many approaches that one could try. I am hoping to hear from someone who successfully solved something similar.

@RadimCernej, Could you share the data as CSV or mat file?

Have you tried Savitzky-Golay derivatives? It does a job for calculating the derivatives of noisy data.

@ACR Yes, I tried Sav-Gol, got so so results. Perhaps I should try wider operators (some 60 pts). I forgot what widths I tried.

Perhaps 1D blob detection is what you are looking for, which involves using the Laplacian of Gaussian filter.

@mhdadk Yes, that is what I am planning to try next. Probably quite wide kernel, 30 to 60 points.

@RadimCernej I've used Viterbi for vocal pitch-tracking, where there's a difference between noisy/moving continuous sounds and discrete state changes between notes or voiced/unvoiced. Not a direct analogy, but that's where my suggestion came from.

@Royi According to what I read, attachments are not supported by StackExchange and using external links is problematic. This is the formula for the synthetic data in the picture:
i: 0 to 3999
x= 5.0*i
if x <= 10'000.0
y=1000+0.1x-0.00001x^2+120.0*RAND(0.0 to 1.0)
if x > 10'000.0
y=1000+0.1x-0.00001x^2+120.0*RAND(0.0 to 1.0)-500.0

@RadimCernej, You can put a CSV in GitHub Gist and link here. You can link a zip file from your drive, etc...

@Royi https://gist.github.com/cernejr/17ed740798c41b527c7ef086f3a2e3fd

One simple way to tackle it is to fit a Piece Wise Constant model to the data.
Once it is fitted, locate the sample with the highest derivative magnitude.
The way to model the data is solving the following optimization problem:
$$
\arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} {\left\| \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_{2}^{2}}_{\text{Denoising}} + \lambda \underbrace{\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} \left| {x}_{i + 1} - {x}_{i} \right|}_{\text{Sparse 1st derivative}} = \frac{1}{2} {\left\| \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{y} \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| \boldsymbol{D} \boldsymbol{x} \right\|}_{1}
$$
This is the Total Variation (TV) Denoising model.

Once fitted, becomes:

Now, calculate the finite differences of the model signal and display the magnitude:

As can be seen, it is quite easy to locate the sample which indicates the abrupt change.
The problem is solved using ADMM which gives the same results as the DCP solver.
More methods are illustrated at Wikipedia - Step Detection.
The full code is available on my StackExchange Signal Processing GitHub Repository (Look at the SignalProcessing\Q94226 folder).

The article by Laurent Condat, pointed to by one the links in this answer, is very very promising.

https://lcondat.github.io/download/Condat_TV_1D_v2.c

@RadimCernej, You may find a Julia code in my repository. It should be pretty easy to convert it into c once you have a matrix multiplication function (Use BLAS).

If your steps are always greater than noise, then maybe a simple discrete derivate could fit your needs:
$dx[n] = x[n]-x[n-1]$
The instant where the derivate is higher than a given threshold points the step location:
$instants=( |dx[n]|>Threshold )$
the variable $instants$ will be $0$ everywhere except in the step locations which will have $1$.
In addition, you can also consider that abrupt changes are distinct from noise peaks: the first have a one way derivative, while the second have a two way excursion.

I am realizing that the synthetic data I posted is too "nice", my bad. No, simple differences are so noisy that changepoints cannot be easily identified. I also tried savgol smoothing+differentiating kernels, got so so results.

I have added an additional possibility, still following the same idea. A more complex approach would be to use wavelet decomposition and entropy.
